# display_timer_callback: unexpected state when scroll

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uicollectionview

So I am making a calendar with collection view and every time I scroll up or down I get this in the console:

ProjectName[4926:900232] [WindowServer] display_timer_callback: unexpected state (now:1c820e75c8a < expected:1c820eb748c)

I set up everything programmatically . The app did not crashed but I keep getting this.

Comment: did you ever solve this?

Answer (score 0):

There isn't a specific solution about this problem. On Apple developer forum the only response is in this thread [On Log Noise](https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/115461)